# In Mechanize how do I determine response type for a post_connect_hook

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I am following Jimm Stout's [suggestion](http://jimmstout.com/2012/adding-a-default-content-type-to-mechanize-agent/) for websites that don't set content-type.

```
  agent = Mechanize.new do |a|
    a.post_connect_hooks << ->(_,_,response,_) do
      if response.content_type.empty?
        response.content_type = 'text/html'
      end
    end
  end
```

How do I avoid setting the Content-Type if I get a redirect, a 40x or a 50x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sure the response class is `Net::HTTPOK`.

```
agent = Mechanize.new do |a|
  a.post_connect_hooks << ->(_,_,response,_) do
    break unless response.class == Net::HTTPOK
    if response.content_type.empty?
      response.content_type = 'text/html'
    end
  end
end
```